# building package using configure - how to rope in updated versions of libs/headers

Tags: linux, configure

I'm trying to build R.3.3.2 on a SuSE Linux server. It is a routine configure/make/install kind of setup.
It relies on some libs/headers that are either missing on my server or are older than required versions. As  I run `./configure` I get messages like:

```
configure: error: "liblzma library and headers are required"
```

I can download and build the missing packages in my home dir (with `--prefix=$HOME/packages`) as there is enough guidance on R website, but will appreciate guidance  in how to build the final target (i.e., `R`).

If I build with packages installed in my home dir (by updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) then everyone has to include my `packages/` to their paths.
OTOH I am reluctant to add all these new packages to `/usr/lib64/` because I am unsure version change impact on other programs. My search path shows:

```
$ gcc -Xlinker --verbose  2>/dev/null | grep SEAR | sed -e 's/SEARCH_DIR//g'
("/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/lib64"); ("/usr/lib64"); ("/usr/local/lib64"); ("/lib64"); ("/usr/x86_64-suse-linux/lib"); ("/usr/local/lib"); ("/lib"); ("/usr/lib");
```

which shows that a standard lib version is going to be picked before `/usr/local/lib64`

So my question is how does one generally resolve this kind of issue?

It also made me think perhaps I should static link *only* these new packages. Maybe it's a wrong kind of thought :|  but I am also unclear what command line options for `./configure` to do this. I will appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It is checking for dependencies so we need to install
the `xz-5.2.2.tar.gz` file first which you will get from this site:
http://tukaani.org/xz

Then go to Download Directory and execute these commands

```
tar xzvf xz-5.2.2.tar.gz
cd xz-5.2.2
./configure --prefix=$HOME/packages
make -j3
make install
```

Hope it will work for further any help please post your queries with proper error snapshot